# Error, "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" when using system()

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have encountered this problem about a year ago and just gave up, but I really need to figure this out.
I have the following lines of code which give me the error "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". I cannot find the solution to my problem, as this error seems to be a lot more specific to how the code is layed out than other errors. All I want is to create a folder in %APPDATA% called ".whatever", and I think system would be easiest.

**Code**:

```
char* APPDATA_PATH = getenv("APPDATA");
system("md " + APPDATA_PATH + "\\.whatever");
```

What am I doing wrong? I find conversion of some types in c++ can be quite irritating.

Comment: You are adding adresses. Use real C++ strings: [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and you won't have this issue.

Comment: `"md " + APPDATA_PATH` You seem to believe this is the way to concatenate two strings. It is not - in fact, it's syntactically meaningless, which is what the compiler is telling you. One way would be to use `std::string`, like this: `system( (std::string("md ") + APPDATA_PATH + "\\.whatever").c_str() );`

Comment: That is very helpfull. Thank you.